# How to cost minimize among markets

Tags: r, cost-optimization

Hello there and thanks in advance.
I have the current problem.
I have a dataset that looks like this

```
data <- data.frame (id = 1:3, A = 1:3, B = 1:3)
```

Where:

- id are products
- A and B represent the price of every id product on markets A and B, although i might have in future n times markets C,D, etc

My objective is to arrange a solution that shows up where is better to buy every id product.

Something like a data frame showing the best place to buy from every id item.

I have read some optimization packages info, so far i have no clue on how i can get this done. I think those packages might be for more complex tasks.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the Quantitative Finance Forum might be a better venue but I suspect they might expect a more specific example. At any rate this is not sufficiently about a well explained with coded data as a programming task.

Comment: Please show the expected result and discuss how you want to deal with ties given that every row in the sample input is a tie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example isn't great, since A and B have the same value in each row; therefore neither A nor B is 'better' (i.e. lower). A more useful example is:

```r
data <- data.frame(id = 1:3, A = c(2, 4, 3), B = c(3, 5, 2))
```

In which case you can do:

```r
library(dplyr)

data %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(best = names(.)[which.min(c(A, B)) + 1])
#> # A tibble: 3 x 4
#> # Rowwise: 
#>      id     A     B best 
#>   <int> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>
#> 1     1     2     3 A    
#> 2     2     4     5 A    
#> 3     3     3     2 B
```